# dynamic query postgres

Tags: postgresql, dynamic

I am new to postgres and running following dynamic query

```
EXECUTE 'Select * from products';
```

I get following response.

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "'Select * from products'" 
LINE 1: EXECUTE 'Select * from products';
```

I Know this would be something basic I m missing

Answer (score 3):

There is the `EXECUTE` statement of **plpgsql**, which would do what you are trying to do - execute an SQL query string. You tagged [dynamic](/questions/tagged/dynamic), so this may be what you are looking for.

Only works inside plpgsql functions or [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) statements (anonymous code blocks). [The distinction between `EXECUTE` and `SQL-EXECUTE` made clear in the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> **Note:** The PL/pgSQL `EXECUTE` statement is not related to the `EXECUTE` SQL
>   statement supported by the PostgreSQL server. The server's `EXECUTE`
>   statement cannot be used directly within PL/pgSQL functions (and is
>   not needed).

If you want to return values from a dynamic `SELECT` query as your example indicates, you need to create a function. `DO` statements always return `void`. [More about returning values from a function in the very fine manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-execute.html):

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> EXECUTE name [ ( parameter [, ...] ) ]
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> `EXECUTE` is used to execute a previously prepared statement.

So `EXECUTE` doesn't execute a string of SQL, it execute a prepared statement that is identified by a name and you need to prepare the statement separately using [PREPARE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html):

```
=> prepare stmt as select * from products;
=> execute stmt;
-- "select * from products" output goes here...
```