# Execute a String Sql in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In a function, I have a `SELECT` query in a string, for example:

```
sql='SELECT * FROM A'
```

I want to execute `sql` output result of: `SELECT * FROM A`

How can I execute the string `sql` in PostgreSQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709624/dynamic-query-postgres

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside a function use EXECUTE.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score -1):

below one works fine in postgres 8.4

```
UDBI=> PREPARE query as select 1 as a;
PREPARE
UDBI=> PREPARE query
UDBI=> EXECUTE query;
 a 
---
 1
(1 row)

UDBI=>
```

Comment: This is not a dynamic query - the `select 1 as a` part is not sent as a string, but as part of the SQL statement. If executed immediately and once only like this, it is equivalent to just typing `select 1 as a;` on its own.