# How to run a query generated from a function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dynamic

Long story short, I have a function written by plpgsql in postgres, this function would do me a favor to generate a `'select * from crosstab.....'` statement in the result so that I don't have to manually type the hundreds of column names for pivot table in this statement. So now if I just copy paste this statement in another query tool and run it, I can get the pivot table generated in the output. However, as you spotted, this process involves man work thus not automatic, I have tried some like `EXECUTE function('which returns the statement I want')`, but I have not yet found the solution...

In order to clarify what I am asking, here I can express in a very simple example.

`select 1+1` returns 2
now i would love to use another key word i.e. `EXECUTE 'select 1+1'` to return 2 as well, how can I do this? I have been searching for a while, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [PL/pgSQL functions: How to return table with an execute statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18084936/190597).

Comment: Related, but not so close to my purpose. Because the reason why I have that function is to let the function automatically created all the hundreds of columns for me, but in the link looks like I need to create another function which I would list all the hundreds of columns I need.

Comment: "If you want to return values from a dynamic SELECT query [you need to create a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10710523/190597)".

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I am researching on it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write your query to a file, for eg doit.sql?
Then in the psql command line editor you can say

```
# \i doit.sql
```

Comment: I believe I would need everything in one place:
create or replace function func():........;

--then run this function result again right after