# How to execute query returned by a function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql function that returns a query in text format. I now need to execute the query. Function is like that.

```
create function func1(clause text) returns text as
$body$ 
declare 
temp text;
begin 
execute format ('select string_agg(name || ' text ', ', ') from table where %s', clause) into temp;

return format('select * from crosstab(%s, %s) as %s',
format('select col1, col2, col3 from table where %s', clause),
format('select distinct col1 from table where %s', clause),
'(name, ' || temp || ')');
)
end;
$body$
```

Now i try to execute the result

```
execute func1('some clause');
```

but i keep getting error `perpared statement 'func1' does not exist`.

How can i execute the resulting query that is returned from the function? I cant return the result of query sinc i dont know the columns that will be returned since all the columns requested this way are user defined on runtime so the construction of the resulting table is fully dynamic and dependant on what the user wants to see.

Comment: I don't know the answer in postgresql functions, but this looks a lot like something you'd normally do in (application) code in my opinion

Comment: That would be one way to do it, but problem is that then there would be alot of back and forth between DB and code since there is a lot of data i need from DB to construct this query. And then result of this query itself is a CTE in another query.

Comment: I guess you'll have to prepare the statement before executing it, with `PREPARE stmt AS ...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709624/dynamic-query-postgres does this help?

Comment: does not seem to work...

Comment: Your function could return a cursor: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html

Comment: `EXECUTE` has different meaning depending on whether it is used in SQL or PL/pgsql. In SQL, `EXECUTE` is a command to run a prepared statement. In PL/pgSQL, `EXECUTE` is a statement that executes a string as a SQL command.

Comment: "*I cant return the result of query sinc i dont know the columns*" - you can still return `SET OF RECORD` iirc

Comment: cant use set of record as a CTE since it requires spesific column names.

Answer (score 1):

For executing a function in PostgreSQL, you can use these formats:

```
select func1('some clause');
select * from func1('some clause');
select id, name, func1('some clause') from anothertable;
```

and sometimes we need to execute our function inside the another function without using the result of function, for this you can use:

```
perform func1('some clause');
```

Additional information, calling or executing procedures in PostgreSQL you can use:

```
call myproc('some clause');
```

You can not use this syntax: `execute myfunc();`

You have some ways to solve your problem.
Change return type of your function from text to set of table and inside the function write return query. This is second way. For example:

```
create or replace function func1(clause text) 
returns setof test.t1 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    return query 
    execute format('select * from test.t1 where %s', clause);
end;
$function$
;

select * from func1('c2 = 10');
-- result: 
tup1    10
tup1    10
```

Write second function for executing your first func1('some clause'). This is second way. For example:

```
create or replace function func1(clause text) 
returns text 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    return format('select * from test.t1 where %s', clause);
end;
$function$
;

create or replace function func2(clause text) 
returns setof test.t1 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    return query 
    execute func1(clause);
end;
$function$
;

select * from func2('c2 = 10');
-- Result: 
tup1    10
tup1    10
```

And third way, you can write procedure and use cursor for returning query.

Comment: setof table wont work as the amount of columns and names of columns are dynamic and defined on runtime by the user.

Comment: @MarkoTaht on PostgreSQL functions can return only same structured data, if you want to return dynamic data, you can use only cursor type for returning.

Comment: @RaminFaracon then i need to get a SQL string out from the function and execute the returned SQL string where i need it. Cause i dont know enough about cursos to evaluate if it suits my needs or not.

Comment: @MarkoTaht  `EXECUTE` only works in PL/PgSQL - ie within functions or do blocks written in the PL/PgSQL language. It does not work in plain SQL. You cannot use dynamic SQL directly in PostgreSQL's SQL dialect.